# How can i convert Linq var to List

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, var

I am trying to convert the Linq var to List.my c# code is

```
private List<HyperlinkInfo> GetHyperlinkByCode()
{
        TourInfoBusiness obj = new TourInfoBusiness();
        List<HyperlinkInfo> lst = new List<HyperlinkInfo>();
        lst = obj.GetAllHyperlink();
        //lst = lst.Select(x => x.Attraction).ToList();
        var k = lst.Select(x => x.Attraction).Distinct();            
}
```

if you look at the above code till the Line var `k = lst.Select(x => x.Attraction).Distinct();` is ok Now can i convert var k to List.

Comment: what are the properties of class `HyperLinkInfo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to your comments you need single `HyperlinInfo` object for each `Attraction` value (which is string). So, use grouping and `ToList()`:

```
private List<HyperlinkInfo> GetHyperlinkByCode()
{
        TourInfoBusiness obj = new TourInfoBusiness();
        List<HyperlinkInfo> lst = obj.GetAllHyperlink();
        return lst.GroupBy(x => x.Attraction) // group links by attraction
                  .Select(g => g.First()) // select first link from each group
                  .ToList(); // convert result to list
}
```

Also you can use [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=d4396b9ff63932be0ab07c36452a481d20f96307) **DistinctBy** extension (available from NuGet):

```
private List<HyperlinkInfo> GetHyperlinkByCode()
{
        TourInfoBusiness obj = new TourInfoBusiness();
        List<HyperlinkInfo> lst = obj.GetAllHyperlink();
        return lst.DistinctBy(x => x.Attraction).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Enumerable.ToList<TSource> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx). Just Add `ToList()` at the end of your query or

```
return k.ToList();
```

So your method can be:

```
private List<HyperlinkInfo> GetHyperlinkByCode()
{
        TourInfoBusiness obj = new TourInfoBusiness();
        List<HyperlinkInfo> lst = new List<HyperlinkInfo>();
        lst = obj.GetAllHyperlink();
        //lst = lst.Select(x => x.Attraction).ToList();
        var k = lst.Select(x => x.Attraction).Distinct();
        return k.ToList();
}
```

But `x.Attraction` should be `HyperLinkInfo` type object.

**EDIT:** Based on comment it appears that `x.Attraction` is a string, you need to create object of your class `Project.Bll.HyperlinkInfo` in select statement and then return that list. Something like:

```
var k = lst.Select(new Project.Bll.HyperLinkInfo(x => x.Attraction)).Distinct();
```

Assuming that `Project.Bll.HyperlinkInfo` constructor takes a string parameter to return a `HyperLinkInfo` object.

Comment: Its not working..The Error Message is  "Error 8 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Bll.HyperlinkInfo>'

Comment: @KartikPatel, check the edited part, you need to select `HyperLinkInfo` type object.

Comment: still not working and x.Attraction is part of HyperLinkInfo type object.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var k = lst.Select(x => x.Attraction).Distinct().ToList();
```

Now `k` is List of `x.Attraction` type. If your `x.Attraction` is `string`, use this:

```
List<string> k = lst.Select(x => x.Attraction).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Not working...getting an error like...Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Bll.HyperlinkInfo>'

Comment: I have to return object of HyperLinkInfo.I cant use List<string?

Comment: @KartikPatel You have selected `x.Attraction` which is string. How do you want to convert `string` in to `HyperLinkInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ToList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to your query;

> Creates a `List<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
List<HyperlinkInfo> k = lst.Select(x => x.Attraction).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Not working....Getting an Error like Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Bll.HyperlinkInfo>'

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
return (List<Hyperlink Info>) k
```

Answer (score 0):

try this add DistinctBy of [moreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

and call it in your code:

```
lst.DistinctBy(x => x.Attraction).toList();
```